# present navigation controller from another navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that's embedded inside a `UINavigationController` and I want to present another navigation controller from inside the `UIViewController` of the first navigation controller.

The problem is that when I present and dismiss that `UINavigationController` the back button of the first navigation controller disappears, I want to present `navCtrl` and when I dismiss it the back button of the first `UINavigationController` remains

```
VendorsViewController* vendorsVC = [[VendorsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VendorsViewController" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray* vendorListArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.cachedVendorList.crossSearchResults];
[vendorListArray insertObject:@"All Vendors" atIndex:0];
UINavigationController* navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vendorsVC];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:YES];
```

Comment: How to do you dismiss your second navigationController?

Comment: @FahimParkar that is not true, where do you base your opinion?

Comment: How many view controllers are in the first navigation controller's stack? If there is only one, there shouldn't be a back button. If not, say you present a second navCtrl in the second view controller of the first navCtrl, when the second navCtrl is dismissed, there should be a back button.

Comment: try to present on self rather than self.navigationController

Answer (score 3):

Create your second `UINavigationController` and set its `rootViewController` as your `UIViewController`. Then on your `UIViewController` set a button/control with an action to dismiss your `UIViewController`.

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:nil];
}
```